# How to engage app.config of WCF Library?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config

I have created WCF Library which has `app.config`. My WCF host application have reference to library and using code to define endpoint, service metadata behavior, etc. So it looks like to me I can configure WCF either programmatically or from app.config. How can I make my host application to regard library's app.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `app.config` file defined in your library does not affect your host application in any way.

In order to make the host application to be configured via config file, just add the `<serviceModel>` section to the `app.config` file of the host application — you can copy it from the WCF library config file.

After that, you can host your service as simple as following:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ICalculatorService));        
host.Open();
```

Comment: Once I will have `app.config` file, how to create ServiceHost instance? Do I still need to specify base address, endpoint data?

Comment: @Pablo, these config settings will be handled automatically for you upon creation of the WCF service instance. You'll still be able to configure certain things in the code, but you don't have to specify base address and endpoints if the config file contains these settings.

Comment: `ServiceHost` class doesn't have constructor without base address.

Comment: A small example depicting how to create `ServiceHost` which will solely rely on `app.config` would be great.

Comment: @Pablo actually you can create a `ServiceHost` without passing any `baseAddress`. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487(v=vs.110).aspx): `baseAddresses` have `params` modifier, so it is valid not to pass anything.

Comment: @Pablo, added the example — actually, it's pretty simple :)